# Performance advantage of 32bit registers in AArch64?

Tags: assembly, cpu-architecture, apple-m1, arm64, cpu-registers

When doing integer operations in AArch64/ARM64, is there a performance difference when using 32bit W{n} registers versus 64bit X{n} registers?

For example, is `add W1, W2, W3` any faster than `add X1, X2, X3`? Is `sdiv W1, W2, W3` faster than `sdiv X1, X2, X3`? Could it be different depending on implementation (like Apple M1/M2/M3 vs. a 64bit Qualcomm Snapdragon)?

My intuition is there is a minor performance advantage when using W{n}, but I'm not sure whether it actually matters except in tight loops. I'm interested in official ARM documentation talking about this, if there is one. In assembly code I'm currently writing, I'm using mostly X{n} for consistency, but am wondering whether it's worth switching to W{n} when I know/expect the data to fit into 32 bits.

Comment: *I'm interested in official ARM documentation* - You tagged [apple-m1], which is a microarchitecture not designed by ARM at all, so they definitely won't have published an optimization guide for it.  I'd expect that it's like x86-64: simple ops like `add` and shift are the same speed with either operand-size, but `sdiv` could be slower.  Or it might only depend on the magnitude of the values, so 64-bit registers might be the same speed for values that could have fit in a 32-bit register.  On some low-end CPUs, 64-bit multiply might be slower.

Comment: ARM has performance numbers for some of their cores, like Cortex-A77 (https://developer.arm.com/documentation/pjdocpjdoc-466751330-1105/latest) has latency, throughput, and info on which execution pipe they compete for, for every instruction.  Apple M1 reverse-engineered CPU-architecture details primarily by Maynard Handley: https://www.reddit.com/r/ReverseEngineering/comments/pos7hb/apple_m1_crowdsourced_reverseengineering_doc/  / https://gist.githubusercontent.com/travisdowns/00e87165356a0e698b49d6cdbf091dd5/raw/5d73ec198acec71cef60b91d67456e476168f742/M1%2520Explainer%2520070.pdf

Comment: (Unlike x86-64, there's no code-size advantage to using narrower registers: all AArch64 instructions are 4 bytes.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Thank you, those are very good sources! The Cortex A77 optimization guide lists some "W-form" and "X-form" differences, for divide and multiply accumulate, and some memory load/stores. No differences in other arithmetics. So your first suspicion in your first comment seems to be spot-on.

Comment: Another thing to check for is that if you have signed 32-bit data in memory, and want to use 64-bit arithmetic, then you'll have to sign-extend when loading, which could have a cost.  On Cortex A-72, there's no penalty for single loads, but load-pair does: `LDPSW X0, X1, [X2]` looks to be a extra uop compared to `LDP W0, W1, [X2]`.

Comment: There's also the point that if you're writing a function with 32-bit integer arguments, they are passed in `Wn` with the upper 32 bits of `Xn` undefined, so if you want to use 64--bit arithmetic you have to spend another instruction to zero- or sign-extend each one.

Comment: @DarkDust: One note about the ARM optimization manuals is that they don't list assembler aliases, so you have to look up each instruction by its "true name".  In particular, `mul` is an alias for `madd ..., xzr`, so your observation about multiply-accumulate being slower applies to plain multiplication as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The links provided by @PeterCordes and comment by @NateEldredge have sent me down some interesting rabbit holes.

**tl;dr:** For arithmetics like `ADD`, `SUB`, `LSL` and so on, there is no performance difference when using W{n} vs. X{n}. However, there is a slight W{n} advantage when doing `udiv`/`sdiv`. Depending on implementation (Cortex vs. M1), the way `ldp` and `stp` are called can yield a tiny difference.

Sources:

- [Arm Cortex-A77 Core Software Optimization Guide](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/pjdocpjdoc-466751330-1105/latest)
- [List of M1 instructions and their cycle times](https://dougallj.github.io/applecpu/firestorm-int.html) and [Firestorm Pipeline Overview](https://dougallj.github.io/applecpu/firestorm.html) by Dougall Johnson
- [M1 Explainer](https://github.com/name99-org/AArch64-Explore/blob/main/vol1%20M1%20Explainer.nb.pdf)

---

## Cortex-A77

I suspect this probably applies to most AArch64 implementations.

- Advantage when using W{n} over X{n}:

  - `udiv`, `sdiv`: Exec latency of 5 to 12 for W-form, 5 to 20 for X-form.
  - There is no difference for multiply accumulate (`madd`, `msub`) and thus no difference for "pure" multiply.
- Penalty when using W{n} over X{n}:

  - `ldp`, `ldnp` with signed immediate offset: Throughput of 2 for W-form, but just 1 for X-form.
  - `stp`, `stnp` with signed immediate offset: Throughput of 2 for W-form, but just 1 for X-form.
  - Interestingly, there's no difference when using load/store pair with pre- or post-index. So `ldp W0, W1, [SP, #-16]` (no exclamation mark) has a penalty, but `ldp W0, W1, [SP, #-16]!` and `ldp W0, W1, [SP], #16` do not!

---

## Apple M1

The implementation of AArch64 by Apple significantly differs from Cortex versions. Here's what I was able to find out:

- With load/store pair, the picture is reversed when comparing with Cortex!

  - `ldnp` and `stnp` have no difference when using W-form or X-form.
  - `ldp` and `stp` are very slightly *faster* in W-form for pre- and post-index, but for the signed-offset case they're the same speed.
  - `ldr` and `str` are also very slightly *faster* in W-form. The difference seems to be even smaller than with `ldp`/`stp`.
- Advantage when using W{n}:

  - `udiv`, `sdiv`: Exec latency of 7 to 8 for W-form, 7 to 9 for X-form.
- Penalty when using W{n}:

  - `mov W0, W1` must be executed, whereas `mov X0, X1` is just a register rename internally.
  - `mov` from/to SP is slightly slower with W{n} registers.

---

## Conclusion

As far as I can tell, one of the few cases one might care about W-form vs. X-form is when doing lots of `udiv`/`sdiv` on Cortex. On M1, the difference is tiny. Overall, the differences are small when they do exist and I suspect simply don't matter much in real-life code.

The other scenario that occurs to me where the difference might be important is implementing a `memcpy` with unrolled `ldp`/`stp`: on Cortex, doing signed-offset and just one pre- or post-index call could be slightly faster, while on M1 it's probably better to use pre- or post-index calls for all `ldp`/`stp`.

Comment: *5 to 12 for W-form, 5 to 20 for X form* - so performance might be the same for the same number since the best case is the same, and the worst case for 64-bit is less than twice as slow for twice as many bits.  So it might only be slower if you actually use larger numbers, where the W form wouldn't have been an option.

Comment: *`mov W0, W1` must be executed*  vs. `mov X0, X1` being eliminated in register rename.  - Interesting, x86-64 CPUs can eliminate both 64-bit and 32-bit zero-extending moves, but x86-64 has code-size incentive to use 32-bit operand-size, and needs more `mov`s in general being mostly a 2-operand ISA for scalar integer.  So I guess on AArch64 you might favour using 64-bit register copies if you don't *need* zero-extension, or can do it earlier or later as part of an `add` or something.